# Sending files with java and ports

Tags: java, networking

I was reading the answer to this question:
[How to transfer files from one computer to another over the network using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109307/how-to-transfer-files-from-one-computer-to-another-over-the-network-using-java)

and I didn't understand part of jjnguy's answer. What should the LISTENING_PORT be? How do you decide what port to use? And what is CONNECTION_ADDRESS?

I realize these are very basic networking questions, so maybe someone can point me in the direction of a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Socket call has this signature

public Socket(String host, int port)

[See documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

CONNECTION_ADDRESS is a string (probably) of the quad unsigned byte form (for IPV4) i.e. 192.168.0.2

LISTENING_PORT can be any number between 0 and 65535 though numbers < 1024 or so are assigned to well known services (read up on IANA)

Here is an example:

If you put this in your browser address bar: 74.125.132.94:80 you should see google.

note that in this case it is CONNECTION_ADDRESS:LISTENING_PORT (there is a separating : )

This says connect to 74.125.132.94 on port 80 (HTTP)

Basically every machine has an IP address (CONNECTION_ADDRESS) and the application you are creating will listen on a specific LISTENING_PORT. Dependant on what you application is doing you would assign EITHER an appropriate IANA service port or an arbitrary port number above the IANA range so...

If you were creating a web server application for example then you would set the application to listen on port 80 as that is the standard HTTP web port

OR

Lets say you are creating a random game application that is serving people in your game the you would just choose a random number above 1024 i.e. 12345

Then you would create your client and have it connect to port 12345 / 80 on what ever IP the server is located at (you can work out that server IP by running IPCONFIG (Windows) or whatever command is applicable for your servers OS environment.

Comment: in java CONNECTION_ADDRESS is probably declared as private string CONNECTION_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"; and LISTENING_PORT is probably private int LISTENING_PORT = 12345; The documentation for Socket is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: Excellent, exactly the sort of introduction I was looking for.

Comment: What would happen if you assigned an "inappropriate" port to transfer files, say, a port used for email?

Comment: Nothing really - it's just a convention. Lets say you coded a server application for a game that listened on port 110 or 25 (conventional smtp ports) for client requests. As long as what the client sent is understood by the server the server would respond and both client and server wouldfunction correctly. You may find that someone odd might try connect their mail client to your game server but their mail client just wouldn't work as it would send commands your game server wouldn't understand... no biggy! HTH

Answer (score 0):

Any [port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_and_UDP_port), i.e. a number between 0 and 65535. The IP [address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) or name of the server accepting the connection. Try the Wikipedia article explaining [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) or this [Sun/Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html).

Comment: to the point but sometimes laymans terms can be a lot more helpful than dry documentation