# Transfer a Text File

Tags: java, file, minecraft, file-transfer

I will start to code a CloudSystem for Minecraft Servers but I really don't know how to get the Log from the Servers to the Main Application.

My Plan:

Have an Main Application where the Main Server runs on. The Application starts, stops and restart the Sub Servers. The Sub Servers also have an Application(a Plugin).

So I can get the Log File from the Sub Servers via the Application that runs on them. But how can I transfer the Log File to the Main Application?

Thanks for replys :)
Sincerly Calvin

P.S. Sorry if I have failures in the text, or if it is not understandable, I'm from Germany

Comment: Are they all on the same machine? If not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109307/how-to-transfer-files-from-one-computer-to-another-over-the-network-using-java) could help giving you ideas.

Comment: @dly Thanks a lot. It's really simple O.o I didn't emagine that. And yes, they can run on different machines.